# SweetAlert Configuration Confusion

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I'm trying to use SweetAlert 2.1.2 with the following configuration:

```
swal({
    title: "My Event Title",
    text: "My event message",
    icon: "warning",
    html: true,
    closeOnClickOutside: true,
    content: {
      element: "input",
      attributes: {
        placeholder: "User text",
        type: "input"
      }
    },
    buttons: {
      cancelMove: {
        text: "Cancel",
        value: "c"
      },
      sendConfirm: {
        text: "Yes, continue",
        value: "s"
      },
    }
  },
  function(value) {
    switch (value) {

      case "cancelMove":
        swal("Move cancelled");
        break;

      case "sendConfirm":
        swal("Sending confirmation ...");
        break;

      default:
        swal("Good bye!!!");
    }
  });
```

But, I'm not getting the expected results of a text input and two buttons:
[image]

I think I'm following their configuration steps correctly. But, obviously I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

During button clicking with its defined value you're passing in `value` this button value. I mean `cancelMove` sends `value = c` and `sendConfirm` sends `value = s`.

Also use `.then(` instead of `}, function(`.

Working snippet below:

```js
swal({
    title: "My Event Title",
    text: "My event message",
    icon: "warning",
    html: true,
    closeOnClickOutside: true,
    content: {
      element: "input",
      attributes: {
        placeholder: "User text",
        type: "input"
      }
    },
    buttons: {
      cancelMove: {
        text: "Cancel",
        value: "c"
      },
      sendConfirm: {
        text: "Yes, continue",
        value: "s"
      },
    }
  }).then((value)=>{
 
    switch (value) {

      case "c":
        swal("Move cancelled");
        break;

      case "s":
        swal("Sending confirmation ...");
        break;

      default:
        swal("Good bye!!!");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```